# Как добавить QLineEdit на QGraphicsScene c возможностью редактировать текст

Tags: c++, qt

Не столько вопрос, сколько совет нужен 
1) Я могу добавить на QGraphicsScene QLineEdit просто через 
scene->addWidget
Но тогда при нажатии на QLineEdit не появляется курсор. Надо добавить какие-то eventCliced или что-то такое, да? Они у меня не переопределены.
2) Я могу создать виджет, на котором уже создать QLineEdit, и только после этого добавить виджет с лайнэдитом на сцену. Но тогда вокруг него появляется уродская рамочка, которая мне не нужна абсолютно. Её можно наверно как-то ужать через size? 
*И вообще, мне просто нужны поля для ввода текста на QGraphicsScene с чёрным контуром, потому что это для штампа чертежа...* 
Или можно ещё что-то сделать с этим безобразием?(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если задача просто редактировать текстовые поля на сцене, то проще так:

```
QGraphicsScene * scene = // ...
QGraphicsTextItem * field = scene->addText("text");
field->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextEditorInteraction);
```

Можно установить и другие [флаги редактирования](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#TextInteractionFlag-enum).